# Chrome input fields not presenting Windows numeric keypad (tabtip)

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, numbers, on-screen-keyboard

We have found that since Windows 10 1709 was rolled out, the Windows on screen keyboard does not switch to numerical input when selecting number fields in Chrome:

[image: Chrome e.g.]

This does continue to work in Internet Explorer:
[image: IE e.g.]

The HTML to produce the number field:

```
<div>
    <input type="number"/>
</div>
```

It doesn't look like Microsoft is interested in investigating the issue, as they believe its a Chrome problem, but using the same versions of Chrome in VM's running Windows 10 before the 1709 version do work OK, and we get the keyboard we'd expect to see.

We first noticed the issue on Chrome 65.0.3325.181, which still works on any version of Windows prior to 1709. Within 2 months, Windows 8 started behaving the same way.

Does anybody have any idea how we can circumvent this? The MS case we opened 6 months ago is just being ignored, and we can't find any info anywhere else on the web regarding it.

We have a product built on the Chromium engine, so if there's a way to fix this with some HTML/CSS/js hack, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that since 1709, Windows introduced a new TabTip keyboard. We had the same issue in a Kiosk web app and we discovered this registry setting:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7 
Create a DWORD value named
DisableNewKeyboardExperience
With a value of 1.
This reverts to the old keyboard, where numeric auto-switch with Chrome works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks, its not worked straight off the bat that, but you've given me a lead.I can see it tries to use the old one (and even resizes the background window), but then flicks straight back to the new one. Can I ask, where did you find out about this key?

Comment: Update: Once I upgraded to Chrome 71.0.3578.80, this started working. Thanks again